# Copy multiple ranges and paste it to a different sheet, in the same row and in the last blank row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro where, i load several files, copy the first sheet of every file and bring the sheets to the "Master" file.

From here, the macro creates a summary of all the new sheets loaded into a pre defined sheet called "Summary" and does the same to another sheet called "Errors".

I'll share the code with the "Errors" sheet because is where my question relies (This portion of code, does not copy and paste multiple ranges, yet):

You can see, this code copies all the data in the range D5:N until the last row and paste it in the "Errors" sheet starting from the last blank row.

```
      Sub WorksheetLoopSummary()

         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim D As Integer
         Dim E As Integer
         Dim lastrow As Long
         Dim SumRange As Range

         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

         For E = 5 To WS_Count

            Sheets(E).Select

            If Range("F5") = "" Then

            Else

            lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
            Range("D5:N" & lastrow).Copy
            lastrow = Sheets("Errors").Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
            Sheets("Errors").Range("A" & lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            End If
         Next E

End Sub
```

Now, i realized that i need to copy an additional range as well, here an example:

[Source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9MZg.png)

The range in yellow is the one i'm copying now, with no problem, but i will need to copy the range/cell in pink too ant paste it to the "Errors" sheet with the following order:

[Errors Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11TUa.png)

To do this i have this code, works perfect (im getting to my question, i promise)

```
Sub CopyPasteMultiRange()
Dim rng As Range
Dim R1 As Range
Dim R2 As Range
Dim mRange As Range
Dim C As Range
Dim LastRowErrors As Integer

LastRowErrors = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    Set R1 = Range("D5:N5")
    Set R2 = Range("B8")
    Set mRange = Union(R1, R2)

Dim WSEntries As Worksheet
Set WSEntries = Sheets("Errors")

Dim LastRowErrorsSum As Integer
LastRowErrorsSum = WSEntries.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Integer
i = 1
For Each C In mRange
    WSEntries.Cells(LastRowErrorsSum + 1, i) = C
    i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```

MY PROBLEM: As you can see, this last code does not copy the data to the last row of the range "D5:N", to paste it to my Errors sheet in the order i want.

MY QUESTION: How can i combine these codes to do the following:

1- Copy range "D5:N" to last row and for each row of data, copy the range "B8" (for each row).

2- Paste the data into the "Errors Sheet" to reach this outcome:

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu93r.png)

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I hope i explained myself properly, if not, i apologize.

Thanks in advance!